# Finding a formula / algorithm for generate evenly distributed rounded number in a given range?

Tags: algorithms

Given two numbers (a start and endpoint) I want to create an even distribution of the numbers in that range but rounded to a "nice to see number".

For example, I have the start and numbers 277 and 1171.
Mentally, I would output something like this:
[200,350,500,650,800,950,1100,1250]

The rounded range should round down 277 and the upper number should round up 1171 (how I got 200 and 1250). 250 would be acceptable as a lower number round down as well.

Another example is 55-600 would output something like:

[0, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]

I'm not really sure about how to go about this and translate my mental thinking down into a formula where I could input any range and get some evenly divided numbers back.

Comment: Did you mean to include 50 in your second example?

Comment: Anyway, you'll need to specify approximately how many numbers you want in your output. Once you know that, you can choose a step size, and then you can determine the bounds.